# Paginate data from two tables that are sorted by the creation date and located in different databases

Tags: javascript, python, java, mongodb, postgresql

Table A is in a PostgreSQL database, while Table B is in a MongoDB database.

I want to paginate the data in both tables programmatically and without merging them, and the result pages should be ordered by the `creation_date` attribute in both tables.

---

Example:

Schema of table A in database X:
`A(id, name, creation_date, ...)`

and it contains:

| id | name | creation_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | ... | 2023-01-18 15:00 |
| A2 | ... | 2023-01-18 14:00 |
| A3 | ... | 2023-01-18 13:00 |
| A4 | ... | 2023-01-18 11:00 |
| A5 | ... | 2023-01-18 10:00 |
| A6 | ... | 2023-01-18 08:00 |

Schema of table B in database Y:
`B(id, name, creation_date, ...)`

and it contains:

| id | name | creation_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B1 | ... | 2023-01-18 12:00 |
| B2 | ... | 2023-01-18 09:00 |
| B3 | ... | 2023-01-18 07:00 |
| B4 | ... | 2023-01-18 06:00 |
| B5 | ... | 2023-01-18 05:00 |
| B6 | ... | 2023-01-18 04:00 |

Let's say the items per page is 5, the result of each page should be:

Page 1:

| id | name | creation_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | ... | 2023-01-18 15:00 |
| A2 | ... | 2023-01-18 14:00 |
| A3 | ... | 2023-01-18 13:00 |
| B1 | ... | 2023-01-18 12:00 |
| A4 | ... | 2023-01-18 11:00 |

Page 2:

| id | name | creation_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A5 | ... | 2023-01-18 10:00 |
| B2 | ... | 2023-01-18 09:00 |
| A6 | ... | 2023-01-18 08:00 |
| B3 | ... | 2023-01-18 07:00 |
| B4 | ... | 2023-01-18 06:00 |

Page 3:

| id | name | creation_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B5 | ... | 2023-01-18 05:00 |
| B6 | ... | 2023-01-18 04:00 |

---

What is the most efficient solution to do this using code?
It makes no difference what programming language is used. I'm just looking for an optimized algorithm and hopefully it can be converted into any language.

Comment: Does the requesting of a page have to be done by requesting a specific page number or would a creation_date to start searching from also be sufficient as a starting point?

Comment: I didn't understand your question.
I'm looking for a solution that works with either traditional pagination or infinite scroll, so going to a specific page isn't necessary as long as I can get to the next page every time.

Comment: I'll be more specific in my solution then. The first page is straight forward, simply get the last 5 entries from both databases, which with an index on creation_date will be fast. Combine the results in your application and give back the last 5 of the 10 entries retrieved. For the next page give the creation_date of the 5th entry from the first page, from both databases fetch the last 5 entries that happened before the given date (still fast if indexed) and merge the 10 results into a single page of 5 again. Repeat ad infinitum for infinity fast paging.

Comment: Disadvantage of this method however is that 1) you can't for instance request page 3 at will since you would need the know the creation_date of the last entry on page 2 and 2) the uniqueness in the order of entries needs to be strict so if creation_date isn't unique across the two databases you'd need to add an extra unique identifier to sort on and give that back in the response as well.

Comment: Yes, this is the approach I've been considering and have decided to implement. Regarding  the second point, the creation date uniqueness, I didn't think about using it, but to use an offset or maybe the identifier which is unique. Assuming we have 5 items per page, if we take 4 from table A and 1 from table B for page 1, then in page 2 I'll get 5 records from table A starting at index 5, and same for table B but starting from index 2.

Comment: Offset could still lead to performance issues since the database would still need to visit previous records in order to find the starting point. Using a unique identifier sounds like a good solution to me as long as entries do not get deleted.

Comment: Can you explain how using an offset will cause performance issues?
Note that I am planning to skip N number of items depending on the offset. It is possible to skip items both SQL with something like `SELECT * FROM A LIMIT 5 OFFSET 4`, or in MongoDB with `db.A.find().skip(4).limit(5);`.

Comment: With offset the database will still need to go through the offset rows, they are only dropped at the end of the query. So in your case it would still need to go through 5+4=9 rows instead of just the 5 you want as result. If the offset is a large number the performance will deteriorate as a result.

Comment: OK. I get your point. Is it possible to provide me with a simple example (in basic SQL syntax and/or MongoDB query language) on how to implement your solution?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM A WHERE creation_date < '2023-01-18 11:00' ORDER BY creation_date DESC LIMIT 5`, `SELECT * FROM A WHERE ROW(creation_date, id) < ('2023-01-18 11:00', A4) ORDER BY creation_date DESC, id DESC LIMIT 5` and `SELECT * FROM A WHERE creation_date < (SELECT creation_date FROM A WHERE id = A4) ORDER BY creation_date DESC LIMIT 5` would all work. Solution 1 requires uniqueness on creation_date, solution 2 requires two input parameters and solution 3 requires that rows cannot be deleted. In your case all three solutions should work just fine.